# Displaying records in android grouped by their date

Tags: android, sqlite, instant-messaging

I'm trying to create a mock messaging app.

I'm entering all the messages sent by me to an inbuilt Database(SQLite) with the following columns - ID, FROM, TO, MESSAGE, TIMESTAMP and displaying the messages along with the time at which they were entered into the database but, I'm having trouble figuring out a way to group all messages sent on a particular date and assigning a date label to those and then a new date label for the next group of messages sent on another date (like how it appears on whatsapp).

Comment: Search for SectionIndexer and Filterable examples in Android

Comment: http://www.motzwrit.es/post/18090937895/listview-fastscroll-with-sectionindexer-in-mono-for

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply asking for a way to summarise the number of messages for each date? If so, a simple SQLite query such as this would suffice:

```
Select date(datetime(timestamp/1000, 'unixepoch')) AS Date, COUNT(*) AS MessageCount FROM Messages GROUP BY Date
```

Alternatively, forgive me, I'm unfamiliar with how WhatsApp works :)